# 日付を使用したJavaのパッケージ名がエラーになる

Tags: java

D:¥dev¥java¥20180729
という位置にあるmainクラスのパッケージ名を
dev.java.20180729
にしたところエラーが出ました。
ネット上で調べて見ても「ディレクトリの階層と同じ様に付ける。」というような事しか書いてなく、私物の本にも同じような事が書いて有ります。どの様にするのが正解なのでしょうか。

ちなみにこのようなコードでこのようなエラーが出ました

ソース

```
package "dev.java.20180729";

public class Main{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        System.out.println("HelloWorld");
    }
}
```

エラー
[Java] Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens

Comment: 参考までに、どんなエラーが出たのかを(そのままで構わないので)質問に含めてもらうとアドバイスが付きやすいかもしれません。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

質問の例で言うと、`20180729`がパッケージ名の命名規約に違反しているためと思います。
最初の文字は[`Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(int codepoint)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isJavaIdentifierStart-int-)が`true`を返す文字である必要があり、慣例的に言えば、アルファベットである必要がある、ということです。

＃厳密にどの文字が使えるかは、上記文書を参照してください。(※Java8のjavadocです)

ちなみに、2文字目以降については[`Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(int codepoint)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isJavaIdentifierPart-int-)で判断します。

＃数字も利用可能です。

---

なので、

> 「ディレクトリの階層と同じ様に付ける。」

というよりは、

> パッケージ名と同じ階層のディレクトリを作成し、そこにファイルを配置する。

と理解するのがよいと思います。

#### 追記

ソースコード例が追記されたので、回答を追記します。

```
package "dev.java.20180729";
```

の箇所のダブルクオートは不要です。
前述の回答と合わせると、例えば`20180729`を`d20180729`にして、

```
package dev.java.d20180729;
```

と記述すればよいです。(当然ファイルは`dev\java\d20180729`以下に配置)